# Error while training with datasets using neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I'm facing a problem while making a project. I have to train my program with a dataset file in order to predict after. It is concerning chess game. This is

```
RES: 1/2-1/2
CHECKMATE: False
FEN: 8/8/8/8/3K2kP/r5N1/1R6/8 b - - 0 62
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . K . . k P
r . . . . . N .
. R . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
```

a content exemple. RES and checkmate are the expected and the board the input.

I'm making an algo based on neural network training.
This is the high parts of my code.

```
def network_creator(sizeof_input, sizeof_output, sizeof_hidden):
    weight_one = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(sizeof_hidden)] for j in range(sizeof_input)]
    weight_two = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(sizeof_output)] for j in range(sizeof_hidden)]
    return weight_one, weight_two
def file_parser(file):
    chess_states = []
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        i = 0
        while i < len(lines):
            line = lines[i]
            if line.startswith("RES:"):
                res = line.strip().split(' ')[1]
                checkmate = lines[i + 1].strip().split(' ')[1]
                fen = lines[i + 2].strip().split(' ')[1]
                chess = []
                i += 3
                while i < len(lines) and not lines[i].startswith("\n"):
                    chess.append(lines[i].strip())
                    i += 1
                chess_states.append({
                    "RES": res,
                    "Checkmate": checkmate,
                    "FEN": fen,
                    "CHESS_Board": chess
                })
            else:
                i += 1
    return chess_states

def board_parser(chess_ine):
    my_dict = {'.': 0, 'k': 1, 'r': 2, 'p': 3, 'K': 4, 'b': 5, 'B': 10, 'R': 6, 'Q': 7, 'q': 8, 'P': 9, 'N': 11, 'n': 12}

    new_value = [my_dict[c] for c in chess_ine.strip() if c in my_dict]
    return new_value

def res_parser(res):
    if res == "1-0":
        return 1.0
    elif res == "0-1":
        return 0.1
    elif res == "1/2-1/2":
        return 0.5

def extract_data(chess):
    X_train = []
    Y_train = []
    for one in chess:
        # print(one["CHESS_Board"])
        inputs = board_parser("".join(one["CHESS_Board"]))
        # print(inputs)
        expected = (res_parser(one["RES"]), one["Checkmate"])
        # print(expected)
        X_train.append(inputs)
        Y_train.append(expected)

    return X_train, Y_train

def forward(X, weight_one, weight_two):

    layer_hidden_input = [sum(x * w for x, w in zip(X, weight_one[i])) for i in range(len(weight_one))]
    layer_hidden_output = [activation_function(x) for x in layer_hidden_input]

    layer_output_input = [sum(h * w for h, w in zip(layer_hidden_output, weight_two[i])) for i in range(len(weight_two))]
    layer_output_output = [activation_function(x) for x in layer_output_input]

    return layer_hidden_output, layer_output_output

def backward(X, y, layer_hidden_output, layer_output_output, weight_two):
    error_out = [t - p for t, p in zip(y, layer_output_output)]
    alpha_calcul = [e * activation_function_der(p) for e, p in zip(error_out, layer_output_output)]

    error_hidden = [sum(alpha_calcul[j] * weight_two[i][j] for j in range(len(alpha_calcul))) for i in range(len(layer_hidden_output))]
    alpha_calcul_hidden = [e * activation_function_der(h) for e, h in zip(error_hidden, layer_hidden_output)]

    return alpha_calcul_hidden, alpha_calcul

def update(X, alpha_calcul_hidden, alpha_calcul, layer_hidden_output, weight_one, weight_two, lr):
    for i in range(len(weight_two)):
        for j in range(len(weight_two[i])):
            weight_two[i][j] += layer_hidden_output[i] * alpha_calcul[j] *lr

    for i in range(len(weight_one)):
        for j in range(len(weight_one[i])):
            weight_one[i][j] += X[i] * alpha_calcul_hidden * lr

def weighted_sum(expected, mine):
    res = sum((t - p) ** 2 for t, p in zip(expected, mine)) / len(expected)
    return res

def forward(X, weight_one, weight_two):

    layer_hidden_input = [sum(x * w for x, w in zip(X, weight_one[i])) for i in range(len(weight_one))]
    layer_hidden_output = [activation_function(x) for x in layer_hidden_input]

    layer_output_input = [sum(h * w for h, w in zip(layer_hidden_output, weight_two[i])) for i in range(len(weight_two))]
    layer_output_output = [activation_function(x) for x in layer_output_input]

    return layer_hidden_output, layer_output_output

def backward(X, y, layer_hidden_output, layer_output_output, weight_two):
    error_out = [t - p for t, p in zip(y, layer_output_output)]
    alpha_calcul = [e * activation_function_der(p) for e, p in zip(error_out, layer_output_output)]

    error_hidden = [sum(alpha_calcul[j] * weight_two[i][j] for j in range(len(alpha_calcul))) for i in range(len(layer_hidden_output))]
    alpha_calcul_hidden = [e * activation_function_der(h) for e, h in zip(error_hidden, layer_hidden_output)]

    return alpha_calcul_hidden, alpha_calcul

def update(X, alpha_calcul_hidden, alpha_calcul, layer_hidden_output, weight_one, weight_two, lr):
    for i in range(len(weight_two)):
        for j in range(len(weight_two[i])):
            weight_two[i][j] += layer_hidden_output[i] * alpha_calcul[j] *lr

    for i in range(len(weight_one)):
        for j in range(len(weight_one[i])):
            weight_one[i][j] += X[i] * alpha_calcul_hidden * lr

def trainer(X, y, epochs=1000, lr=0.1):
    sizeof_input = len(X[0])
    sizeof_hidden = len(X[0])
    sizeof_output = len(y[0])

    weight_one, weight_two = network_creator(sizeof_input, sizeof_output, sizeof_hidden)
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        layer_hidden_output, layer_output_output = forward(X, weight_one, weight_two)
        loss = weighted_sum(y, layer_output_output)
        alpha_calcul_hidden, alpha_calcul = backward(X, y, layer_hidden_output, layer_output_output)
        update(X[0], alpha_calcul_hidden, alpha_calcul, layer_hidden_output, weight_one, weight_two, lr)
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {loss}")
    return weight_one, weight_two

def main(argv):
    ac = len(argv)
    for i in range(0, ac):
        if argv[i] == "--new":
            if int(argv[i + 3]):
                sizeof_input = int(argv[i + 1])
                sizeof_hidden = int(argv[i + 2])
                sizeof_output = int(argv[i + 3])
                created_network, e = network_creator(sizeof_input, sizeof_output, sizeof_hidden)
            else:
                sizeof_input = int(argv[i + 1])
                sizeof_output = int(argv[i + 2])
                sizeof_hidden = int(math.sqrt(sizeof_input * sizeof_output))
                created_network, e = network_creator(sizeof_input, sizeof_output, sizeof_hidden)
            print(created_network)
            print(e)
        if argv[i] == "--save":
            save_file(argv[i + 1], created_network)
        if argv[i] == "--load":
            loaded_file = load_file(argv[i + 1])
            print(loaded_file)
        if argv[i] == "--train":
            fiile = file_parser(argv[i + 1])
            X_train, Y_train = extract_data(fiile)
            trained_one, trained_two = trainer(X_train, Y_train)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit(main(sys.argv))
```

This is the error i'm encountering:

```
layer_hidden_input = [sum(x * w for x, w in zip(X[i], weight_one[i])) for i in range(len(weight_one))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: error suggests that you have wrong index in some variable, or you use smaller object. maybe write it as normal `for`-loop - so you could put some `print()`, `print(len(...))` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: when i print X it shows me my input converted into int like i have done it (it is a list of list of int of size) and weights_one are random_weights generated (list of list of floats). Size of X is 40 and size of weights_one[i] is also 40 so it have same size .

Comment: but what is size of `weights_one` without `[i]`? Maybe you have to use `weights_one[0][i]` instead of `weights_one[i]`?